# WaitForDebugEvent (kernel32.dll) bug or what?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, kernel32

i'm new and i need your help resolving this issue.
I'm trying to create a simple debugger to understand how debuggers works and how is loaded exes in memory. I have already written the code which works as well, but now there is the problem: when i try to call WaitForDebugEvent (a kernel32 function) to get the debug event it works, in fact the debug_event variable is written, but this function clears all the variables in my application. So it clear also:

```
this (current form)
EventArgs (arguments of my form load function)
object sender (the object who called the function)
```

So i can't continue executing my app because all the vars were deleted. I wouldn't think this is a kernel32 or a Visual Studio bug...

This is the code:

(Structs and imports got from pInvoke.net and MSDN)

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool DebugActiveProcess(uint dwProcessId);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "WaitForDebugEvent")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool WaitForDebugEvent([In] ref DEBUG_EVENT lpDebugEvent, uint dwMilliseconds);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool ContinueDebugEvent(uint dwProcessId, uint dwThreadId, uint dwContinueStatus);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool DebugActiveProcessStop([In] int Pid);

    public struct DEBUG_EVENT
    {
        public int dwDebugEventCode;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
        public struct u
        {
            public EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO Exception;
            public CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO CreateThread;
            public CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO CreateProcessInfo;
            public EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO ExitThread;
            public EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO ExitProcess;
            public LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO LoadDll;
            public UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO UnloadDll;
            public OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO DebugString;
            public RIP_INFO RipInfo;
        };
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO
    {
        public EXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord;
        public uint dwFirstChance;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct EXCEPTION_RECORD
    {
        public uint ExceptionCode;
        public uint ExceptionFlags;
        public IntPtr ExceptionRecord;
        public IntPtr ExceptionAddress;
        public uint NumberParameters;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint[] ExceptionInformation;
    }

    public delegate uint PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(IntPtr lpThreadParameter);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO
    {
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public IntPtr lpThreadLocalBase;
        public PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress;
    }

    //public delegate uint PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(IntPtr lpThreadParameter);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO
    {
        public IntPtr hFile;
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public IntPtr lpBaseOfImage;
        public uint dwDebugInfoFileOffset;
        public uint nDebugInfoSize;
        public IntPtr lpThreadLocalBase;
        public PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress;
        public IntPtr lpImageName;
        public ushort fUnicode;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO
    {
        public uint dwExitCode;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO
    {
        public uint dwExitCode;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO
    {
        public IntPtr hFile;
        public IntPtr lpBaseOfDll;
        public uint dwDebugInfoFileOffset;
        public uint nDebugInfoSize;
        public IntPtr lpImageName;
        public ushort fUnicode;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO
    {
        public IntPtr lpBaseOfDll;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string lpDebugStringData;
        public ushort fUnicode;
        public ushort nDebugStringLength;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RIP_INFO
    {
        public uint dwError;
        public uint dwType;
    }
```

And the main loop of debugger:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DebugActiveProcess((uint)Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0].Id);
        DEBUG_EVENT debug_event = new DEBUG_EVENT();
        CONTEXT context = new CONTEXT();
        context.ContextFlags = (uint)CONTEXT_FLAGS.CONTEXT_ALL;
        while (true)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                if (WaitForDebugEvent(ref debug_event, (uint)double.PositiveInfinity))
                {
                       ...

                    ContinueDebugEvent((uint)debug_event.dwProcessId, (uint)debug_event.dwThreadId, (uint)0x10002);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What can i do? Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:**

I have rewritten the code in C++ to see if the problem there was there too. But there was no issue... so i think the problem lays only in C#. This is the code in C++:

**IMPORTS:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
```

**CODE:**

```
        private: System::Void DebuggerForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            std::wstring processName = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring, String^>("myExe.exe");
            DWORD id = getProcessId(processName);
            if (id == 0) std::exit(0);
            DebugActiveProcess(id); 

            DEBUG_EVENT debug_event = { 0 };
            while (true)
            {
                if (WaitForDebugEvent(&debug_event, INFINITE)) {
                    // TODO
                    ContinueDebugEvent(debug_event.dwProcessId, debug_event.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
                }
            }
        }

        DWORD getProcessId(const std::wstring& processName)
        {
            PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
            processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);

            HANDLE processesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
            if (processesSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                return 0;

            Process32First(processesSnapshot, &processInfo);
            if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
            {
                CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
                return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
            }

            while (Process32Next(processesSnapshot, &processInfo))
            {
                if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
                {
                    CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
                    return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
                }
            }

            CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe not a good idea to name your variables the same as API functions.

Comment: Which variables were you talking about? (C# or C++ code)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should enable the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege on the targeted process:

(`SE_DEBUG_NAME` = "SeDebugPrivilege")

1. Use `OpenProcessToken` with `TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES` and `TOKEN_QUERY` access flags.
2. Use `LookupPrivilegeValue` to retrieve the LUID of the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege name.
3. Use `AdjustTokenPrivileges` to enable the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege.
4. `CloseHandle`

For the 3rd step you need a `TOKEN_PRIVILEGES` structure, where the `PrivilegesCount` field must set to `1`. Also You must set the first(zero index) item of the `Privilege` field (`Luid`: see 2nd step, `Attributes`: `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`)

The `DEBUG_EVENT` structure:

The `u` field of the structure is an union, it means that it only contains one of the listed structs. Try to use `LayoutKind.Explicit` and decorate every field with the attribute `FieldOffset` to define the correct offset inside the structure. Try this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct DEBUG_EVENT
{

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int dwDebugEventCode;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int dwProcessId;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int dwThreadId;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct u {

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO Exception;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO CreateThread;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO CreateProcessInfo;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO ExitThread;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO ExitProcess;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO LoadDll;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO UnloadDll;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO DebugString;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RIP_INFO RipInfo;
    }
};
```

Comment: Will this resolve my problem... ? I don't think it's a privilege issue. I have done some internet searches and i found it might be an assembly optimization issue of code and variables... I will edit question soon about this

Comment: I think your DEBUG_EVENT structure is not "marshaled" properly. At the first look, I didn't look at your structures, because you said, you imported it from pinvoke. answer updated

Comment: It is not working, it gives me an error on [FieldOffset(12)], the "FieldOffset" is not valid on this declaration type... so i rewritten the code in C++ to see if there the debugging functions worked... and the answer is yes, no problem in C++ (question updated) - so it seems the problem lays only in C# code